# How to color the diameters of a graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

[image]I have this hexagon generated by

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{2}
        \foreach \c [count=\i from 0] in {
            $\overline{1}$,
            $\overline{3}$,
            $2$,
            $1$,
            $3$,
            $\overline{2}$}
            {
            \path (0,0) -- (60*\i:\r) node[circle,inner sep=1mm,fill=black](\i){} --++ (60*\i:10pt) node{\c};
            }
            \foreach \i in {0,...,5}
                \foreach \n in {\i,...,5}
                    \draw (\i.center) -- (\n.center);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

for which I would like to turn the diameters determined by $(2,\overline{2})$, $(1,\overline{1})$ and $(3,\overline{3})$ red (as in the given image above). I am not sure how to do that. I would want the other edges in the graph to stay black. [image]

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

[image]

*Note*: your code fragment doesn't produce showed image

You only need to separate drawing lines between vertices on the black and red part:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        dot/.style={circle,fill, inner sep=1.5pt},
every label/.style={inner sep=0pt}] 
\newdimen\R
\R=1.3cm
   \draw
    (60:\R) \foreach \x in {120,180,...,300} {  -- (\x:\R) };
   \draw[red]
    (300:\R) \foreach \x in {360,60} {  -- (\x:\R) };
   \foreach \i [count=\j] in { \overline{3},2,1,3,\overline{2},\overline{1} }
   {
        \node[dot, label=60*\j:$\i$] at (60*\j:\R) {};
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit (1):**
or with interconnection between all vertices:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        dot/.style={circle,fill, inner sep=1.5pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.style={inner sep=0pt}] 
\newdimen\R
\R=1.3cm
\draw[red]
    (300:\R) \foreach \x in {360,60} {  -- (\x:\R) };
\foreach \i [count=\j] in { \overline{3},2,1,3,\overline{2},\overline{1} }
{
    \node (n\j) [dot, label=60*\j:$\i$] at (60*\j:\R) {};
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
{
\ifnum\i=1
    \foreach \j in {2,...,5}
    \draw (n\i) -- (n\j);
\else
    \foreach \j in {\i,...,6}
    \draw (n\i) -- (n\j);
\fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2):**
Image added in edited answer can be reproduced by:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        dot/.style={circle,fill, inner sep=1.5pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.style={inner sep=0pt}] 
\newdimen\R \R=1.3cm

\foreach \i [count=\j] in { \overline{3},2,1,3,\overline{2},\overline{1} }
{
\node (n\j) [dot, label=60*\j:$\i$] at (60*\j:\R) {};
\draw[red,semithick]  (0,0) -- (n\j);
}

\scoped[on background layer]
{
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
    \foreach \j in {\i,...,6}
    \draw (n\i) -- (n\j);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Black Mild, thank you very much for correcting spelling errors!

Comment: I changed the code in the original post but I am still unsure how to do it. When I am drawing the red edges, how do I do it? Do I use 90 instead of 60?

Comment: @causalityrefilm., sorry, I do not understand your comment. My answer solve your problem as You describe it in question. In your images is angle of 90 degrees ...

Comment: I probably explained it unclearly. I added a picture in my question of what I want.

Comment: @causalityrefilm, image is quite different what you explain your problem Please also correct text in question, I will ad new solution ASAP.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my original question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a TikZ way using syntax `x ? y :z` (meaning `if x then y else z`) and several `\foreach` commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{2}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
\path (\i*60:\r) coordinate (A\i);

\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
\foreach \j  in {\i,...,6}
{
\pgfmathparse{\j-\i-3 ? "black" : "red"}
\draw[\pgfmathresult] (A\i)--(A\j);
}

\foreach \i/\itext in {1/{\overline 3},2/2,3/1,4/3,5/{\overline 2},6/{\overline 1}}
\fill (A\i) circle(2pt) ++(\i*60:.3) node{$\itext$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update** an Asymptote translation

[image]

```
//http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
real r=2;
pair[] A; 
for (int i=0; i<6; ++i) 
A[i]=r*dir(60*i); 

for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
for (int j=i+1; j<6; ++j)
if (j-i==3) 
draw(A[i]--A[j],magenta);
else 
draw(A[i]--A[j],blue);

string[] vlabel={"$\overline 1$","$\overline 3$","2","1","3","$\overline 2$"};
for (int i=0; i<6; ++i){
fill(circle(A[i],.1),purple);
label(vlabel[i],A[i]+.35*dir(60*i));
}
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of the `x ? y : z` syntax in this context.

Comment: a Asymptote translation is added.

Comment: @SebGlav thank you!